# How can you show a picture that disappears after 10 seconds in Android?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

When I click a button (Button1) I want to show a picture on the screen (in full-screen mode) and to play a song (congrats.mp3). After 10 seconds, the user will be redirected to another Activity using intent (SecondGame.class).
How can I do this? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it simply by using Handler thread that will run after 10 seconds.

Put the below code in **onClickListener()** method of your button i.e. when you click the button.Before redirecting you can put any code for what action you want to do.

```
private int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=10000;  // for 10 seconds 

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                    // Code here what you want before redirecting
                    // e.g. hide picture you showed

                    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondGame.class);
                    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashScreen.this);
                    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
                    finish();

            }
        },TIME_OUT);   // parameter to show for a particular time

    }
```